# Desktop Alert Settings in Outlook with Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, alert

I use Outlook 2013 and Powershell for scripting.

I want modify (enable - disabled) some properties like Desktop Alert.

**Tools -> Options -> E-mail Options -> Advanced E-mail Options**

When new messages arrive:

- Play a sound
- Briefly change the mouse pointer
- Show an envelope icon in the taskbar
- Display a Desktop Alert

**Tools -> Options -> E-mail Options -> Advanced E-mail Options -> Desktop Alert Settings -> Preview**

```
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders"
$olFolderCalendar = 9

$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$namespace  = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Most settings like this will be stored in the user's registry. What I would do to find the registry key is compare the registry before and after making the change in Outlook. I use regshot to do this:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/

Then in PowerShell it will be a simple registry key change to enable or disable.

```
Set-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\<SomeKey> -Name Blah -Value 1
```

Comment: Not ***official documentation*** with Registry Paths for those Settings? Or maybe *Class Properties from ComObject outlook.application* but I don't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating further using *Process Monitor* it would seem there is a thread that accesses some of the values in

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\DesktopAlerts
>
> DWORD: TimeOn

Open registry editor, and go to

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Preference\ShowEnvelope

Check the **DWORD** Value of `ShowEnvelope`, modify it to zero if itsn't.

http://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/tip-245-outlook-2003s-desktop-alerts-settings/